# How to bootstrap a test in Spring Boot manually (without @SpringBootTest-Annotation)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm migrating a project from [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) to Spring Boot with [Web Flux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) and got it basically running when I start it manually. However, most of my tests are not working yet. (My `play.Application` obviously can't inject a `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory` as no implementation was bound.) With Play Framework I used to create an application in my tests with:

```
play.Application app = new play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .bindings(
        // here I added a few manual bindings (e.g. mocks)
    ).build();
// Then I could get "beans" out of it:
MyFancyService fancyService = app.injector().instanceOf(MyFancyService.class);
// Or send Http-Requests to it:
Result response = route(app, request);
```

How to do that with Spring Boot?

I've tried/considered:

- Annotating all my tests with `@SpringBootTest(SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` or `@WebFluxTest`, and adding an `@Autowired WebTestClient webClient`. However especially during the migration I would rather not change all my tests too much (the code above is currently only in one place in a `org.junit.Rule`).
- Creating an `ApplicationContext` with `new SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper().buildTestContext().getApplicationContext()`, but could not figure out how to send request to it.

Basically I'm looking for these three key features in Spring Boot (with Web Flux if possible):

1. Adding/Injecting some mocks as services (manually add bindings to the BeanFactory)
2. Accessing some automatically set up services (something like `app.getInstanceOf(MyFancyService.class)`)
3. Sending Http Requests

Comment: the first bullet is the way to go.

Comment: I know it is the idea, however I'm sure you can somehow do it manually and I'd like to know how. (And I'd like to not couple so tightly to a framework and especially during the migration I would rather not change all my tests too much.)

Comment: the point of using a framwork, is to use the framework. If you don't want to get too "tied up" then you shouldn't be using a framework. Then you should be starting the service yourself and executing your tests during a build process. Deploy and start with ansible, execute a jar with rest calls against the service using a bash/python script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out more or less:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class WithApp extends ExternalResource {

    private final WebTestClient webTestClient;

    public WithApp() {
        SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper springBootTestContextBootstrapper = new SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper();
        springBootTestContextBootstrapper.setBootstrapContext(new DefaultBootstrapContext(WithApp.class, new DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate()));
        MergedContextConfiguration config = springBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration();
        ApplicationContext app = new ApplicationContextLoader().loadContext(config);
        MyBean mockedBean = app.getBean(MyBean.class);
        this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(app).build();
    }

    public WebTestClient.ResponseSpec call(HttpMethod method, String uri, Object body) {
        return webTestClient.method(method).uri(uri).bodyValue(body).exchange();
    }

    @Component
    public static class Config {
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public MyBean getMyBeanForTest() {
            return mock(MyBean.class);
        }
    }
}
```